# Can document.write get me into troubles in this case?

Tags: javascript, document.write

I have a simple question. Basically I have index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

   <head>
      <title>Title of document</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <script src="x.js"></script>

      <script>
         iny();
      </script>
   </body>

</html>
```

---

```
// x.js
console.log("x.js");
document.write("<script src='y.js'></script>");

// y.js
console.log("y.js");    
function iny() {
   console.log("iny");
}
```

As you can see, `x.js` loads `a.js` which, in turn, loads `y.js`. Here are the 2 scripts which live in 2 different files:

As you can see `a.js` **syncronously** loads `y.js` using `document.write`.

Now my question is: can document write get me into trouble in this case? My aim is to load `y.js` syncronously and that is the only reason why I am using the write. As far as I know there is no other way. Also it is not an option to have the code of `y.js` copy/pasted in to `x.js`. The 2 scripts **must** remain separate.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need `x.js` in the first place, why not just include `y.js` directly in the page?

Comment: Why do the two scrips need to remain separate, and why do you need to load it synchronously? `document.write` is in general a bad idea, it should not get you in _troubles_ in current browsers, but you shouldn't not relay on that. (It used to have various strange side effects in various browser versions).

Comment: Where is this `a.js`?

Comment: Would it be possible to put the inline script in an external file? You could then use `defer`. `<script src="callToIny.js" defer></script>`.